# How can I transform a .py file into an executable icon in Ubuntu 16?

Tags: python, click, ubuntu-16.04, executable

I'm restarting to learn programming and I want to create a simple .py file that I can execute by double-clicking it.

I already turned the following .py program into an executable file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print("Hello World!")
```

and I already create the .desktop file in the same folder:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=HelloWorld
Exec=/home/david/Desktop/Python/Kana
Icon=
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

But it still is not working.

Obs.: I use Ubuntu 16 and I went in Preferences > Behavior > Executable text files > Run them

Comment: This is answered here: [This Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138908/how-to-execute-a-script-just-by-double-clicking-like-exe-files-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the module pyinstaller (pip install pyinstaller) which will make a .exe of your code, and then run it with wine, even it is not the ideal solution at least it should be working. Here is a great tutorial for pyinstaller: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4

Comment: Thank you very much.

I just found an another Youtube video that helped me: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CTmC5Y7QeM

I tried to install the pyinstaller earlier, but I couldn't.